# Autofill empty rows in a column with previous nonEmpty value in azure dataflow?

Tags: autofill, azure-data-factory

Something similar is possible in Excell,so can it be done in Azure dataflow?

Example:

| Type | Comment | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | value2 | 1 |
| A | value5 |  |
| B | value8 |  |
| A | value2 |  |
| A | value5 | 2 |
| B | value8 |  |
| C | value2 | 3 |
| A | value5 |  |
| B | value8 | 4 |

Final:

| Type | Comment | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | value2 | **1** |
| A | value5 | **1** |
| B | value8 | **1** |
| A | value2 | **1** |
| A | value5 | **2** |
| B | value8 | **2** |
| C | value2 | **3** |
| A | value5 | **3** |
| B | value8 | **4** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this in data flow windows transformation. It needs a partition key for **Over** and a Sort Key for **Sort** in windows settings and in the **Windows** **column** use the expression `last()` to get the previous row Not NULL value to fill in the current value when NULL.

If you do not have a partition key or Sort key, we can generate it in data flow and connect the results to windows transformation.

A pre-developed code snippet is also available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#fill-down). This code creates a

1. `Derived column` transformation with “dummy=1”
2. `Surrogate key` transformation with starting value from 1.
3. `Windows transformation` to Fill down values.

> Note: Source should be added in the dataflow before adding this code snippet.

1. Add **Source**

[image]

2. Add code snippet from the document after the source.

[image]
[image]

3. This code created derived column, surrogateKey, windows transformations.

[image]

4. Edit the Windows column in the **Windows setting** to add the column required to fill down.

   `coalesce(Value, last(Value, true()))`

[image]

5. It fills the NULL values with a previous, not NULL value

[image]

6. In the **sink**, remove the unwanted column in the mapping to get the required output.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fill down in ADF using data flows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#fill-down