# Azure data factory window function last non-null value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to know how to fetch the last non-null value.
Currently I'm using a `lag` function to get the previous value. But if the previous value is null, I want the non-null value before that.

```
lag(value, 1, null())
```

I tried last function : `last(value)`
but it is not working as expected

current formula used : `lag(VALUE,1,null())`

OVER - `ID`

SORT BY - "`DAY_ID`" Ascending

Data:

```
ID, DAY_ID,    VALUE , PREVIOUS_VALUE
1 , 20210101,  2833500,  NULL
1 , 20210102,  2858745,  2833500
1 , 20210103,  2866028,  2858745
1 , 20210104,  2874442,  2866028
1 , 20210104,  null   ,  2874442
1 , 20210105,  2916344, null
```

Expected value :

```
ID, DAY_ID,    VALUE , PREVIOUS_VALUE
1 , 20210101,  2833500,  NULL
1 , 20210102,  2858745,  2833500
1 , 20210103,  2866028,  2858745
1 , 20210104,  2874442,  2866028
1 , 20210104,  null   ,  2874442
1 , 20210105,  2916344,  2874442
```

When I used below, I'm getting VALUE & PREVIOUS VALUE as same except wher VALUE is null, it fetches last value.

```
coalesce(Value, last(Value, true()))
```

Result:

```
ID, DAY_ID,    VALUE , PREVIOUS_VALUE, EXPECTED PREVIOUS_VALUE
1 , 20210101,  2833500,  2833500         null
1 , 20210102,  2858745,  2858745         2833500
1 , 20210103,  2866028,  2866028         2858745
1 , 20210104,  2874442,  2874442         2866028
1 , 20210104,  null   ,  2874442         2874442
1 , 20210105,  2916344,  2916344         2874442
```

Comment: This is not really a Data Factory function but would be either executed via some compute available to you in the pipeline (such as a SQL database, Synapse dedicated SQL pool, Databricks cluster etc) or it might be possible via Mapping Data Flows.  Please add what type of compute is available to you in the pipeline, some sample data and expected results.  Then I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: They're using the ADF lag() function in mapping data flows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#lag

Comment: coalesce() can give you the first non-null value. You might try using that function with a different ordering of your window partition.

Comment: ok thanks @MarkKromerMSFT.  I've added the tag [azure-data-flow] to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Last**: Returns the last item from a collection.

Use **coalesce** with the last function in Azure Data flow Window transformation.

```
coalesce(status, last(status, true()))
```

> **Note**: You will need a key column for over and sort clause in the windows setting to achieve this. You can create a dummy column if you do not one.

Refer to this thread for an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827812/autofill-empty-rows-in-a-column-with-previous-nonempty-value-in-azure-dataflow/68843095#68843095).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.. I tried this but not quite working as expected for my case. I have updated my question with data set.. with results from using both lag & last function.

Comment: using last function to fill in null values, then use lag function to fetch previous values seems to be other option. is there any other way to get the result within single operation

Comment: If you use the last function it fills null values from the previous row. In your data 1st row of value column is not null, but still, you are expecting it as null in previous_value column?